# Can't implicitly convert System.windows.Controls.Image into System.windows.form.control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am totally new to WPF. I am converting application from windows form application to WPF application. windows form application is working properly. I have to create a device for rendering image. for that I Used following code. 
//define a render Control

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Control renderControl;

//get and set rendercontrol

public System.Windows.Forms.Control RenderControl

  {

       get { return renderControl; }
    set { renderControl = value;  }
    }

//PresentParameters

pp = new PresentParameters();

pp.Windowed = true;

pp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;

    device = new Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device(0, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.DeviceType.Hardware, renderControl, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, pp);
```

I import this class and used WPF Image as renderControl. But it generate error can't implicity covert from windows.Controls.Image to Windows.Forms.Control. How I can convert? Is there any other way to render or for Creating device?

Answer (score 0):

WPF controls are not compatible or interchangeable with Windows Forms controls.  The best way to host a Direct3D surface in WPF is to use [D3DImage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28526/Introduction-to-D3DImage).